# undefined reference error in using libx264 in another project

Tags: dll, linker-errors, x264

When I used the x264 DLL in another project, the "undefined reference error" is reported when making that project!

This is my (example_exe.cpp) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define X264_API_IMPORTS
#include "x264.h"


int main(void)
{
    x264_param_t *t;
    x264_encoder_open(t);
    return 0;
}
```

and This is how I compile and make my code:

```
g++ -c example_exe.cpp
g++ -o example_exe.exe example_exe.o -L. -llibx264-142
```

and I got the following error:

```
example_exe.o:example_exe.cpp:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `x264_encoder_open_142(x264_param_t*)`
```

Comment: "... will need to define `X264_API_IMPORTS` before including this header. This clause does not apply to MinGW, similar development environments, or non Windows platforms"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you compile C++ (and not C) than you need to use extern "C" {...} for x264.h header i.e.

```
extern "C" {
#include "x264.h"
}
```